# Adding a module in wildfly common for all the wars

Tags: wildfly

Can anyone suggest me or provide a reference that how I can add a module (adding some jars) in wildfly 10 which has to be available for all the war files.

Thanks
Senthil

Answer (score 4):

See chapter 'Global Modules' of the document [Class Loading in Wildfly](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/Class+Loading+in+WildFly). That should get you started.

Comment: Also note that this doesn't document the module's creation, which can be done through the cli or directly by creating the proper file structure, including the libraries and a module.xml.

Comment: I understand that jboss-deployment-structure.xml is not needed for global modules, right??  
The following update in both standalone.xml and domain.xml and proper module structure is enough, right?                             
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0" >            
  <global-modules>
    <module name="org.javassist" slot="main" />            
  </global-modules> 
</subsystem>

Comment: Yes, jboss-deployment-structure.xml is not required with global module. When we define any module as global module it will be visible to all deployed application.

Comment: the link is broken